# Ajax selection instant change the default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selection

I'm using Ajax to fill a select html element with values from a PHP returned array.

Ajax code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fds_categories').change(function () {
            var template_id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'username' : '<?php echo $user->username; ?>',
                    'categorie_id' : template_id
                },
                url: "ajax/fds_template_ajax.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#fds_price').empty();
                    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, element) {
                        if(element.p == 0){
                            $('#fds_price').append(
                                $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + element.pb + ' Zcard')
                            );
                        }else{
                            $('#fds_price').append(
                                $('<option data-icon="man"></option>').val(element.id).html(element.name + ' Price: ' + element.p + ' Bucks')
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Sadly the values in there won't change the default preview value of the select element.

Example:

GIF image: https://gyazo.com/6aab1545ff143536c17e97eb5ef6315a

As you can see, first I select "Shirts" in the first select menu, then the items would change the attributes in the second select menu, sadly the default preview of the items would stay and wouldnt change. In this case: "Sir scene price". It changes after i selected another item in there.

But is there a way to change the default preview item once I selected an value in the first selection?

---

What I want:

1) Select Shirts from the first select menu,

2) The second select menu should instantly change and show: "Tank price" instead of "Sir scene price".

Does anyone have a idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Add a default  `<option>` that has no value

```
 success: function(data){

       var defOption ='<option value=""> Default text</option>';
       // html() method replaces existing
       $('#fds_price').html(defOption );

       $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, element) {
             .....
       });
}
```

Also note if you set `dataType:'json'` you don't need to parse response yourself